# Changing title didn't change url

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

I have created a survey, but accidentally I put wrong spelling in to it I have changed it from the title and it reflect in all the places except when you go to setting >> survey >> and looked at the URL it shows below.

how do I change it?

Name:
HR Survey

Web Address:

> https://< server name >/sites/General/Community Portal/HR/HR
>   Survey/Lists/**wrong Survey name**/overview.aspx

Description:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't change the URL. In order to have your survey on the correct URL you have to create a new survey.

Title on the other hand can be changed how many times you want. This means that for Swedes (and Danes and Norwegians) with non-english letters like `Å, Ä and Ö` we first create Surveys, Content Types and Pages and more in english (to get a valid readable URL). When created, we change title into local language.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to change the URL.

But you can change the title as a many times you want.